# Automatically show database value after select an option

Tags: javascript, php

Let say i have SQLite's database like this:

```
+----+-----------+-------+
| id | name      | price |
+----+-----------+-------+
| C1 | Car       | 50000 |
| B1 | Bike      | 1500  |
| M1 | Motorbike | 15000 |
| T1 | Truck     | 99000 |
+----+-----------+-------+
```

Then to show the database to the select form i use this code:

```
<form method="post" action="action.php">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Vehicle</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td>                            
                <select name='id_vh' onchange='OnChange(this.value)' required>
                <option selected value=''>choose</option>
                    <?php               
                        $sql="SELECT * FROM vehicle ORDER BY name ASC";
                        $result=$db->query($sql);
                        $row=$result->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                        foreach($row as $dt){
                        echo "<option value='$dt[id]'>$dt[name]</option>";}
                    ?>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

How to show the price automatically after choose the option, i use the code like this but doesn't work:

```
<tr>
            <td>Price</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <?php
            if(isset($_POST['id_vh'])){
                $idv=$_POST['id_vh'];
                $query=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM price WHERE id = '$idv'");
                $query->execute();
                $result    =   $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                echo"<td>$result[price]</td>";
            }
            ?>
         </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set an Id to your Form to handle

```
<form id="vehicleForm" method="post" action="action.php">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Vehicle</td>
      <td>:</td>
      <td>
```

Set an Id to your Selector to handle

```
<select id='id_vh' name='id_vh' required>
  <option selected value=''>choose</option>
  <?php               
     $sql="SELECT * FROM vehicle ORDER BY name ASC";
                    $result=$db->query($sql);
                    $row=$result->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                    foreach($row as $dt){
                    echo "<option value='$dt[id]'>$dt[name]</option>";}
 ?>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Add a jquery file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Add a function to intercept the change

```
<script Type="text/javascript">
  $('#id_vh').on("change",(function (e) {
    /*just for debugging*/  
    alert( this.selectedOptions[0].value);
    /*submit the Form*/ 
    vehicleForm.submit();
}));
</script>
```

That should work. The $_POST will now contain the value of id_vh